# Why does my try catch exception stop working after the catch?

Tags: c++, try-catch

I have a segment of code here that runs partially. I am able to input both the characters (c, a, r) and numbers initially, but after entering a character input, the code no long accepts integer inputs. Why does this happen?

I think it has something to do with my try catch exception.

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int item;
string input;
float total = 0;
int flag = 0;
float maintotal = 0;

int main() {

  cout.precision(2);
  cout << std::fixed;

  cout << "Vending Machine" << endl;
  cout << "----Items------" << endl;

  vendingMachine();
  cout << "Enter c to checkout" << endl;
  cout << "Enter a to add items" << endl;
  cout << "Enter r to remove items" << endl;

  while (true) {
  
    cout << "Enter your selection: " << flush;
    cin >> input;

    try
    {
      item = stoi(input); //convert to int
    }
    catch (exception &e)
    {
        //std::cout << e.what(); 
        flag = -1; //if not set flag
        if (input == "c"){
          checkout();
          
        }
        if (input == "a") {
          add();
          cout << "mainadd total: " << total << endl;
        }
        if (input == "r") {
          remove();
        }

    }

    if (flag != -1) //only execute with no errors
    {
        total = enterSelection();
        
        cout << "total from main: " << total << endl;
    }
  }


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you try set `flag` to `0` in the beginning of the loop?

Comment: I already have it set globally, but that works! why is this tho?

Comment: @yeliah That won't help.  You need to set it each time round the loop.  And for next time, [mre] please, we are not clairvoyant.

Comment: Your handling of `input` is a little odd. Why not check `input` for `"c"`/`"a"`/`"r"` BEFORE calling `stoi()` on whatever remains? And your handling of `total` is a little odd, too.

Comment: @yeliah Please don't edit the code in your question like you did, you are invalidating what has been said in comments and answers (not to mention your edit made the code uncompilable). I have reverted the edit. If you want to make corrections, edit the question to add a new version of the code without changing the original code. Or better, [post your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) that shows what is working for you.  Or give credit to other people's answer(s) that helped you.

Comment: ok, i changed it back

Comment: @yeliah no, actually you changed it to something new, which also doesn't compile (`int float = 0;` is not valid). I have reverted back to the original. Please just stop editing it.

Comment: oops, sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've set flag to -1, it's never changed back to 0. The initialization you perform at the top of the file happens just once, before main is even called. So, after that, when you set it to -1 in the catch block, it never went to a part of the code that set it back to 0. As you saw, setting flag = 0 at the beginning of the while loop corrects that omission.

Comment: should i add `int` or `float` before the `flag = 0` or delete what i have globally?

Comment: @yeliah You really shouldn't be using global variables at all. Make them local to `main()`, or even local to the `while` loop.

Comment: You only need to put the variable type when you're initially declaring the variable. If you write "int flag = 0" at the beginning of your while loop, that will actually be creating a new variable, scoped locally to just the body of that loop. It will also mean that (unless you specify otherwise) the while loop won't see or care about the globally declared flag. Because the flag is apparently only relevant to the loop, and not anything else, I would recommend making it a local variable.